# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

```
function loadCountries(clicked_cat){    

$.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data.Category_1, function(key,val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#myDiv');
    });
}
```

### What this does:

It loads json file perfectly. I am using `data.Category_1` to access the JSON elements.

### What I am not able to do:

I need to add a variable in place of `Category_1` in `data.Category_1`.
It should be something like `data.clicked_cat` where `clicked_cat` gives me details like `Category_1` , `Category_2` etc.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to use a variable as the selector for a parameter of an object?

Comment: Pls add it as an answer, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function(key,val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + data["clicked_cat "]+ '">' + data["clicked_cat "]+ '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#myDiv');
    });
}
```

Comment: Theres no semantic difference between your code and 'data.clicked_cat'